# Tabular-like alignment in algorithm

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-spacing, algorithms, algorithmic, horizontal

Is there a way to encapsulate every line in some dotted lines, and add on the right side 2 columns such that it would look the the picture below? And on every line I can write math equations or something similar? Just how you would calculate the time complexity for an algorithm using the constants method.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\FOR{i = 1..n} 
    \IF {A[i] $>$ 0}
        \FOR{j = 1..i}
            \IF{A[j] mod 2 == 0}
                \FOR{k = 1..j}
                    \STATE s = s + i + j + k
                \ENDFOR
            \ENDIF
        \ENDFOR
    \ENDIF        
\ENDFOR        
\RETURN s
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm1(A[0..n], n)}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

So I would want something like:
[image: this]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which algorithm package are you using? Please always provide a compilable example document.

Comment: @siracusa Surely, I'm not sure which is that I use, but I included a lot of stuff in my document

Comment: @siracusa Hello! I edited it and It's alright now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using `tabularx` to "fake" or "recreate"  the look of the `algorithm` package. The algorithm number is entered automatically, referencing also works:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\FOR{i = 1..n} 
    \IF {A[i] $>$ 0}
        \FOR{j = 1..i}
            \IF{A[j] mod 2 == 0}
                \FOR{k = 1..j}
                    \STATE s = s + i + j + k
                \ENDFOR
            \ENDIF
        \ENDFOR
    \ENDIF        
\ENDFOR        
\RETURN s
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm1(A[0..n], n)}\label{example1}
\end{algorithm}

\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xcc@{}}
    \hline
    \refstepcounter{algorithm}\textbf{Algorithm \thealgorithm}\label{example2} Algorithm1(A[0..n], n) & Cost & Frequency \\
    \hline \vspace{-10pt}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
\FOR{i = 1..n} 
    \IF {A[i] $>$ 0}
        \FOR{j = 1..i}
            \IF{A[j] mod 2 == 0}
                \FOR{k = 1..j}
                    \STATE s = s + i + j + k
                \ENDFOR
            \ENDIF
        \ENDFOR
    \ENDIF        
\ENDFOR        
\RETURN s
\end{algorithmic} & c1 & c2\\[-13pt]
\hline
  \end{tabularx}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\FOR{i = 1..n} 
    \IF {A[i] $>$ 0}
        \FOR{j = 1..i}
            \IF{A[j] mod 2 == 0}
                \FOR{k = 1..j}
                    \STATE s = s + i + j + k
                \ENDFOR
            \ENDIF
        \ENDFOR
    \ENDIF        
\ENDFOR        
\RETURN s
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm1(A[0..n], n)}\label{example3}
\end{algorithm}

Referencing the algorithms:
\ref{example1}
\ref{example2}
\ref{example3}
\end{document}
```

---

Update:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}

\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\footnotesize}rXcc@{}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\refstepcounter{algorithm}\textbf{Algorithm \thealgorithm}\label{example2} Algorithm1(A[0..n], n)} & Cost & Frequency \\
    \hline
     1: & \textbf{for} i = 1..n \textbf{do} & text & other text\\ \hdashline
     2: & \quad\textbf{if} A[i] $>$ 0 \textbf{then} & more text & another text\\ \hdashline
     3: & \quad\quad\textbf{for} j = 1..i \textbf{do} & text & again text\\
\hline
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, how do I add dashed lines between every instruction? And how do I add $c_2,c_3$ for every instructions? It seems like it only lets me do that only for the first line

Comment: @C.Cristi: To do this, you would have to rewrite the whole part in the `algorithmic` environment.  Making the output match the original output of the `algorithmic` environment will be quite difficult then.

Comment: how would you rewrite the whole part?

Comment: What do you mean rewrite the whole part?

Comment: @C.Cristi: I have updated my answer to show you how I would rewrite the algorithm art without using an actual `algorithmic` environment. I have also included dashed lines from the `arydshln` package between every row of the algorithm.